# Is it possible to define instructions to be executed at the end of compilation? (Crystal lang)

Tags: crystal-lang

Let's say a Crystal project is using different shards. And each shard wants to do cleanup at the end of compilation of the overall project. Is it possible using Macros?

Something like this for example:

```
{% at_end %}
  {% system("rm 'tmp files'") %}
{% end %}
```

Comment: Could you explain a specific usecase for this?

Comment: @JohannesMüller I sometimes have to share data between macros. So I write them to a temporary file. If I don't, I would have to use heap memory and capture blocks/Procs the way Kemal does it. It would make things "nicer" if I could delete the temp. files after compilation.

Comment: Interesting idea... but what makes you think tempfiles are more performant than heap allocations? :D

Comment: You probably wont get an answer here as it does not seem to be a thing currently. But you could open a RFC in the Github repo.

Comment: @JohannesMüller The temp files are used during compilation, not for runtime. They store names to be used to generate expressions later during compilation. After compilation, the temp files are no longer used. So during runtime, they would be gone entirely. But, thanks. I'll try the RFC during github.

Comment: You can use constants that are array or hash to store shared state between macros

Comment: Here is an example of shared state between macros: https://carc.in/#/r/372k you can store anything in this kind of storage!

Comment: Thanks @bew.  Would you want to write this as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Done! I added some explanations too ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to share data between multiple macros, you can use `Hash` or `Array`, and access them through a `Constant` which associated AST node is accessible from macros.

Here is an example demonstrating this (live at https://carc.in/#/r/372k):

```
STORAGE = [] of _

macro add(node)
  {% STORAGE << node %}
end

macro list
  {% for elem in STORAGE %}
    {% puts "Elem: #{elem}" %}
  {% end %}
end

add 1
add 2
add "hello"
add :world
add({a: 1, b: 2})
add 3 + 4
add a_call(arg1, 2)

list
```

The important parts here is:

```
STORAGE = [] of _
```

Here I'm declaring an array of a certain type (which is non relevant in this case, as the array is only accessed through macros, you can't use this type (`_`) in normal code). The macro system only needs to know that it is an array.

```
macro add(node)
  {% STORAGE << node %}
end
```

Then I create a macro that will be able to mutate the array AST node (which is type ArrayLiteral in the macro system).
Note that it allows you to store any kind of AST node, from simple nodes like `NumberLiteral` or `SymbolLiteral`, to complex nodes like a `Call`, a `Def` or even a `ClassDef`.

```
macro list
  {% for elem in STORAGE %}
    {% puts "Elem: #{elem}" %}
  {% end %}
end
```

And finally I create a macro that will simply print (at compile time) the content of the `STORAGE` array.

The same can be done with a `HashLiteral`:

```
STORAGE = {} of _ => _
```

And in the same way as explained above, you can use any kind of AST nodes as the key or the value.

---

Note that the `Constants` you use in the macro system can also be seen by normal code, and it's possible to have name clash (what if the user wants to use a constant `STORAGE` too for his own code?).
To minimize this possibility (if this is not wanted), I suggest you to put your constants in a special module like `MyShard::MacroStorage::SomeInterestingNodes` or use some complicated naming pattern like `M____ACRO_Storage____01234` (<-- this is unlikely to be used by the user ;) )

Comment: Wow. I would have never thought of using `[] of _` in a macro. How did you find out about it? (Thanks for this answer. )

Comment: Reading others code, the compiler's code, and experimenting with the edges of the language :D